# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt

I am facing below exception:

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

and --scan gives below:

The build scan was not published due to a configuration problem.

The Gradle Terms of Service have not been agreed to.

For more information, please see https://gradle.com/help/plugin-terms-of-service.

Alternatively, if you are using Gradle Enterprise, specify the server location.
For more information, please see https://gradle.com/help/plugin-enterprise-config.

i have just updated to android studio 4.0 and from then facing above issue.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my sub-modules had some issue to update them even though everything was up to date. When i did it one more time this above error disappeared! Weird that the error i got, to the error studio has shown was nowhere close!!! it don't even shows where the error many of the times.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar error and solved it by checking my room DAO. You should make sure everything is where it's supposed to be.

You could also try

"Build" -> "Clean Project"

..after same thing with..

"Build" -> "Rebuild Project"

..then..

"File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart"

Comment: For me as i said, i followed all the above steps it didn't work. But what the real issue is one of my submodules has some updates, and i didn't even know about that. So whenever i was trying to clean and rebuild its just giving above messages as compiler could not able to find and show me the changed class in submodule.

Answer (score 0):

Recreated the same issue on flutter:
[issue faced- Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUXUm.png)

solution:

Enter your company domain with a single dot **'.'**
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE0wK.png)